# Update table form in another jsf pages didn't work

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2, primefaces-dialog-framework

Pardon me, I've case I would like to ask to you. So I have "dialog" where I put my "`Form create new data`" with `actionListener` into it. but since I using `Model="true"` and the whole screen was disable including my form,I trying put `appendTo="@(body)`, its work. but apparently, actionListener inside the dialog doesn't work.. is anyone can and willing to help me please. it been a week, Its made me crazy.

I using template and template client in my project, pls help

Answer (score 0):

I need some more information about your code and your problem. But on the facts that you give I guess it is the problem that the form have to be inside the dialog. Please try it. If it does not work. Please post your code

Comment: Same here... ;-)

Comment: Hi Guys, thanks for stoping by, anyway this is my code : 


<p:dialog widgetVar="frmDiklat" draggable="true" id="frm" appendTo="@(body)" modal="true" showEffect="fade" showHeader="true" hideEffect="fade" resizable="false">

<p:commandButton value="Save" actionListener="#{dklCon.addDiklat(actionEvent)}" update=":mainForm,grwl" oncomplete="PF('frmDiklat').hide()">
<p:confirm header="Confirmation" message="Are you sure?" icon="ui-icon-alert" />
</p:commandButton>

<p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade">

Comment: Yes I can read it. I post my answer as an edit on my posting to make it clear

Comment: Yes I can read it. But the actionListener is working for me. Could  you edit your question and include your form. The code you posted is ok. But I do not see where actionEvent is from. The parameter is always null in the bean if you do not have this "actionEvent" as a var or something